# 301 redirect not working in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have some rewrite code in my .htaccess file. I have moved a static HTML site into wordpress and need the following to work:

1. redirect http://domain.com.au/ to http://www.domain.com.au/
2. redirect (the old static home page) index.html to http://www.domain.com.au/

I cannot get either to work, I have tried all the various methods that have been suggested. The domain.com.au to http://www.domain.com.au works for all pages except for the home page, e.g. http://domain.com.au/ourteam redirects to http://www.domain.com.au/ourteam

But it will not redirect for the root (home page).

Also I get a page not found error for the index.html redirect.

My .htaccess file is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
### re-direct index.html to root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
### non www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

redirect 301 /team.html http://www.domain.com.au/our-team/
redirect 301 /contact.html http://www.domain.com.au/contact-us/
```

Anyone help - I am tearing my hair out with this!

Comment: I have the similar problem. I tried as well using the Cpanel Redirects, then some Wordpress plugins, then adding this code to .htaccess but nothing seems to work. However it works the same code on other websites.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, i just had trouble with this and found:
[Using htaccess to 301 redirect, not working](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-htaccess-to-301-redirect-not-working)

Apparently you have to put the redirects above the #begin wordpress as apache processes the rewrites and never gets to your redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

### non www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

### re-direct index.html to root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.domain.com.au/ [R=301,L]

redirect 301 /team.html http://www.domain.com.au/our-team/
redirect 301 /contact.html http://www.domain.com.au/contact-us/

# WrodPress rules begin here...
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `rewrite` rules you need to set up the 301s in a rewrite format that's the only way it will work.

```
RewriteRule ^/team.html$ http://www.domain.com.au/our-team/ [R=301,L]
```